# How can reconcile output to $ k e^{rx} $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

When you start with

$y'(x) = r y(x)$

give it one data point and solve for $y(x)$, you always get something of the form

$y(x) = k e^{rx}$

where $k$ is a constant determined by the data point

When $y(c) = d$ and $c$ and $d$ are constants you get

$y(x) = d e^{-rc+rx}$

How can you reconcile this output with the formula

$y(x) = k e^{rx}$

My answer:

$y(x) = d e^{-rc + rx}$
can be rewritten as $d (e^{-rc} e^{rx})$. If $y(c) = d$ and $k=d$, then $d$ is the $y$-intercept and $c=0$. Therefore, the formula can be simplified to

$y(x) = k e^{rx}$, where $k=d$.

This was wrong because it only works when $c=0$ and they are looking for a more general solution of $k$ in terms of $d$,$r$ and $c$. How do you find the correct answer?

Comment: Simply take $k=de^{-rc}$

Comment: I was thinking maybe it was that but they said in terms of d,r and c and that solution includes the e.

Comment: $e$ is a constant, so you would exclude something like $d^2$ because includes the $2$?